# How to test all the projects or libraries in NestJS (nx)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nomachine-nx

We have setup a NestJS project with multiple libraries in it using Nx. We are able to run tests of projects/libraries independently like,

```bash
npx nx test lib1 --coverage
```

This works fine, but we have several libraries and modules, we want to run test across all and consolidate the coverage. How can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in nx documentation, you can run the following command to run all tests

```
 nx run-many --target=test
```

The attached link is to their documentation regarding this

https://nx.dev/nx/run-many#examples